# Mac OS X Lion On external drive cant boot

Tags: macos, mac, operating-systems, xorg, osx-lion

I have the full installer of Mac OS X Lion, that's 3.76 GB, I can install it on a virtual machine, but the OS is too slow, When Installed it to the external drive and boot it onto both Mac Mini (Late 2014) and MacBook Pro (2015) I get a prohibition sign, [The sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pelTE.png)

I have tried the InstallESD.dmg Method.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot boot from any macOS [OS X] older than the Mac you are trying to boot.

The minimum OS for both those Macs is Yosemite, 10.10

There are, of course, no drivers for hardware that wasn't yet invented.